# Fix Android Screen Rotation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, rotation

I have a website I need to show different pages depending on how user is watching the site. If its on desktop, they'll see one page, if its on mobile portrait they'll see one different page, and if its on mobile landscape, same thing, another different page is loaded.

So I've added this javascript code, which at first worked just fine in Android, but now only works in iphone or ipads, but not in Android devices. Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Thank you very much!

Nacho.

```
    var redirectOrientation = function(){
    var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (uagent.search("android") > -1) {

    if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == 270 )  {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("landscape")<0){
window.location.href="http://www.creo.com.uy/web/mytho/inicio-landscape/";
    }
    }
    if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 )  {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("mobile")<0){
       window.location.href="http://www.creo.com.uy/web/mytho/";
    }


        }

else {

    if (window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90 )  {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("landscape")<0){
       window.location.href="http://www.creo.com.uy/web/mytho/inicio-landscape/";
    }
    }
    if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 )  {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf("mobile")<0){
       window.location.href="http://www.creo.com.uy/web/mytho/";
    }
    }
    }
}
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange',redirectOrientation);
    window.addEventListener('onorientationchange',redirectOrientation);


    redirectOrientation();
```

Comment: I just skimmed the code, but you may be better off checking the width/height of the screen rather than relying on a window.orientation value.

Comment: In fact, i should change more things here, as all the pages are redirected and i just need the homepage redirected...